# Make text in the middle of a <td></td> and overflow them in HTML

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Does anyone here know how to make the text to position in the center, and make them overflow than left/right HTML cell if the text is too long?
See the attachment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnHid.png

Comment: you asked 14 questions, but never accepted any as valid answer. I hope you will like someone's answer this time. No pressure :)

Comment: Some of the answer not really match to what i need, so i have no choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To center align text inside a  just add the proper css style as shown below:

```
<td style="text-align:center;white-space:nowrap">This text will be at center</td>
```

Goodluck!